# Disabled index still incurs overhead when inserting

Tags: sql-server, index

I have a 38 million row table that I periodically truncate and refill.  I disable the indexes (non-clustered) when I do this.  But when I included the Execution Plan I noticed SQL Server 2005 is still updating the indexes as I insert the data.  How can this be?

---

Paul White has asked for some documentation.  I created a test script to simplify the event.  In summary, this is what I found.  Consider a table with a clustered index and 2 non-clustered indexes.  If the 2 non-clustered indexes are disabled, they are ignored when inserting data as expected.  But if the clustered index is also dropped, then the 2 non-clustered indexes ARE updated during the insert.   I am only allowed 2 links so I included my DDL script and the execution plan that shows the disabled indexes being updated.

- [IndexTesting4Inserts.sql](https://sites.google.com/site/facesmapicons/IndexTesting4Inserts.sql?attredirects=0&d=1)
- [IndexesOnLine.sqlplan](https://sites.google.com/site/facesmapicons/IndexesOnLine.sqlplan?attredirects=0&d=1)
- [IndexesDisabled](https://sites.google.com/site/facesmapicons/IndexesDisabled.sqlplan?attredirects=0&d=1)
- [ClusteredIndexDropped](https://sites.google.com/site/facesmapicons/ClusteredIndexDropped.sqlplan?attredirects=0&d=1)

Comment: It is possible that it is showing you the plan based on the previous state where the index wasn't disabled, but when you execute the command it will detect the change and recompile a new relevant plan. Do you see that index if you include the actual execution plan and execute the command?

Comment: Yes, this is the actual execution plan.

Comment: What on the "IndexesDisabled" plan are you interpreting as the non clustered indexes being maintained?

Comment: The IndexesDisabled plan is fine and shows expected behavior.  It's the ClusteredIndexDropped plan that shows the NC indexes being maintained.

Comment: @ah - Yes. Exactly. It is expected. The "IndexesDisabled" plan doesn't show any maintenance for the NCIs though.

Comment: Martin, I edited my above reply because I didn't accurately read your reply before posting.  Sorry.

Comment: I see. Looks like disabling the NCIs then dropping the CI causes the NCIs to become re-enabled! The `is_disabled` flag in `sys.indexes` gets reset to `0`

Comment: This is contrary to [the documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190645.aspx) though which seems to suggest dropping the CI leaves NCIs disabled.

Comment: I would of never thought of that.  Thanks Martin!  How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: @Martin: Confirmed. I found this also happens if a clustered index is *created* when there are disabled NCIs. I guess it's because the index is rebuilt going from heap <--> CI regardless of whether or not it's disabled.

Comment: @JonSeigel - Yes I found [a connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/732350/create-clustered-index-enables-disabled-nonclustered-indexes-by-design-or-not-documentation-unclear) stating that way round is expected. Haven't found one for the reverse yet though.

Comment: I would drop the non-clustered indexes and leave the clustered index as is.  The data will then be sorted as you insert it. Add the non-clustered when finished.

Comment: Excellent!  Please mark as answered.